# OAuth 2 and managing multiple user access tokens for server side

Tags: go, oauth, server, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have a server-side app (implemented in GO) which **fetches** user data **from an external API.** (*user data is stored by a 3rd party companies and they provide API to access it*.) I have actually two types of users. One of them is patients and other is a doctor. Doctor actor here is responsible for monitoring patient data. So the flow is,

1. Patients (1..n) authorize the server-side application using OAuth2 grant access token flow.
2. Server regularly fetch patient data via API and stores patient data on a local DB
3. The doctor can check any patient data any time which has been stored on local DB

Step 1 is easy. Implementing OAuth2 grant flow, I can get access_token and refresh_token for each user. Let's say I have 100 patients. I am assuming that I can obtain up-to-date access_token using refresh_token without patient interaction again.

**Question is,** After patient authorized the app, I need to store his/her access_token and refresh_token somewhere so that whenever server starts a scheduled job to fetch patient data, then the server can access external API using a valid token.  What is the general approach here? Should I store access_token and refresh_token on my user table and use them whenever needed?

Since I have n patients (n tokens) and server can fetch external API anytime, then I need to find a consistent way to support this scenario.

Please see the attached diagram for visualization.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Which provider? For Google OAuth you need the Client ID, Client Secret and Refresh Token. With those three you can refresh an Access Token.

Comment: In my case the provider is Fitbit. But I believe Client ID, Client Secret, and Refresh Token is universal to refresh an access token for oAuth 2 standard right? So you suggest storing only refresh_token after the first authorization?

Comment: Just those three items are required to generate a new access token. I wrote a couple of articles using curl to experiment with OAuth. https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-refresh-access-token/

Comment: Thanks, @JohnHanley So you basically suggest that, whenever the server starts a new query to API, the very first step should be refreshing the access token (actually generating a new one as we won't store access token) is that correct? (as we will have only client id, client secret and refresh token so we need to have  a access token)

Comment: No, I am not saying that. I just meant that you only need those three items to refresh an access token. I recommend saving the access token for use until it expires and then refreshing.

Comment: The diagram is wrong. You ask clients to authorize to API and THEN store tokens to SERVER.

Comment: @Max Diagram shows that clients authorize the API so that app can access the API for the client. I haven't shown all connections if it is not related to question. So yes client should authorize the API accessing the authorization server using the redirect URL provided by the app. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need just a single token record for a user, the user table could be a good storage for it. You can consider creating a new one-to-one associated table for it, so you can apply any necessary constraints (not-null and such). You can also use any other safe storage.

You must store the refresh token. Whether to store access tokens and their expiration times (from the `/token` endpoint response), depends on how often you fetch the patient data. If your scheduled task period is longer than the access token lifetime, then you don't need to keep them in a persistent storage. Otherwise, you can store them along with their refresh token.

I don't think there is some general approach, since the solution depends on your requirements and architecture. You can consider storing the tokens in an encrypted form to improve security. I guess you do it with other patients sensitive data anyway.

Just for clarification, the flow you are using is called the [Authorization code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1).